# Is there any powerful html editor on Mac os?

Tags: html, macos, visual-studio

Visual Studio is so powerful and convenient as HTML,CSS and JS editor.

After typing div,it automatically types /div for me.Espresso can do this as well, but it just doesn't types the TAP or space*4 automatically,that's awful!

So, is there any web editor on Mac as powerful as Visual Stdio.Thanks!

By the way, vs2013 Pro is free for students.

Comment: Try Zend Studio. It does all that and it even has shortcuts for elements, JavaScript code completion and much more.

Answer (score 3):

There are many good editors for HTML, CSS and JS for Mac like Espresso, Coda 2, TextMate.

But I personally prefer [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) + [Emmet](http://emmet.io/) combination.

[Emmet Documentation](http://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/)

Check [this](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/26/goodbye-zen-coding-hello-emmet/) link also for some of the features of Emmet.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Emmet is much better than what i want.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you take a look at Sublime Text, TextMate or Coda 2?

Comment: I have tried all of them. But none of them automatically type the close tag.I don't understand why so many people like Coda2.

Comment: I think there extensions for Sublime that may do that for you.

Comment: The power of Sublime Text is in the extensions, as mentioned by @DanGoodspeed
Follow this link: https://sublime.wbond.net/installation to install package control, and then explore the repositories by cmd-shift-p / 'package control: install package'.

Answer (score 2):

You may find [TypeMetal](http://coherencelabs.com/typemetal/) productive for HTML content authoring. It makes the easy stuff easy, while providing unrestricted access to HTML's full element set. TypeMetal produces streamlined, professional-grade markup, while enabling you to work with fully styled content in a keyboard-shortcut-rich environment. You can find links to a free demo build and the complete online user guide [here](http://coherencelabs.com/news/2013/11/25/learning-about-typemetal/). (I designed and developed TypeMetal to be the "missing HTML editor" I've long wished for -- hope you'll enjoy it too!)

Answer (score 0):

You can try learning and customizing vim ( = !